# Created horizontal list of image links that expand onhover. Lines appearing next to images onhover, why?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, onhover

[Live page](https://128adea15bfc1bafb9f65665da2a849fe09dc13a.googledrive.com/host/0B71AnQstJeptYUpjOW9ZLXpTWmc/all.html), [CSS Source](https://128adea15bfc1bafb9f65665da2a849fe09dc13a.googledrive.com/host/0B71AnQstJeptYUpjOW9ZLXpTWmc/all.css), [Page source](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B71AnQstJeptYUpjOW9ZLXpTWmc)

If you hover over the Twitter icon, you should see that a dark blue line appears to the right of the icon that disappears when you move your mouse off. This happens to all the icons except the "Donate" icon. I suspect this is because the icon blocks the view of the line, though your guess is as good as mine. Can anyone tell me why this mysterious line is popping up? I don't know how it got there because I was using an editor with live page updates and assumed it was a glitch.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you

```
a {
text-decoration: none;
}
```

By default text-decoration is underline for anchor tags.